# Maximum function in Gurobi API C++

Tags: c++, constraints, gurobi

I need to add the following constraint to my model written in C++ to call Gurobi

```
max{x_1-x_2, 0} >= 1
```

I have found `addGenConstrMax`, but this adds the maximum constraints directly, and in my case I need the maximum to be greater than 1.

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution without requiring explicit maximization constraints is to introduce a new variable with a lower bound of 1. Then just set this new variable `z` to satisfy `x_1 - x_2 >= z`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact, I have a more complicated expression that involves the max function, I have a way to transform it into a linear one, but I wanted to know how Gurobi performs if we give the max function directly.

Comment: The main idea of the max constraint is to give you a new variable that represents the maximum of some set of variables. You can then use this variable to enforce the >=1 condition, for example.